# How to work around `using K = ...` in MSVC 2012?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, c++11, types

It appears that MSVC 2012 doesn't support `using K = ...;`-type declarations. For example, with the code:

```
template <class Map>
inline void foo(Map &m)
{
  using K = typename Map::key_type;
  using V = typename Map::mapped_type;
  // ...
}
```

The result is a syntax error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='
error C2873: 'K' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

How can I work around this missing feature of MSVC 2012, without upgrading the compiler?

Comment: Microsoft's support for C++11 is incomplete. This is one of the things they're missing. But in this case, you should be able to use an old-fashioned `typedef`.

Comment: @dlf: I figured... how would I go about using the `typedef`?

Comment: `typedef typename Map::key_type K;` should work.

Comment: @dlf: You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: The Visual C++ compiler has a really bad gag reflex. Probably why it doesn't get a lot dates.

Comment: @Claudiu A real gentleman would convince Microsoft to get with the program! :-D

Comment: @dlf Well the feature was added in MSVC 2013. So I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @remyabel Glad to hear it. That means I've just got to convince management to get with the program and let us upgrade! :-D

Comment: -1 for not reading compiler's manual and complaining about an old version of the compiler.

Comment: @abyx: that seems silly

Comment: Damn guys is it really that bad a question to ask how to work around an old version of a compiler?

Comment: @Claudiu your question wasn't "what should I use instead of `using` in MSVC2012". what you actually asked - "here is an obscure error, I use an old compiler, pls help rtfm for me" and this is a bad question.

Comment: @Abyx: Hmm alright. I didn't realize that's what I was asking, before I asked the question, but I've modified the question now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft's support for C++11 is incomplete, and this is one of the things that's missing in VS2012. But in this case, you should be able to use an old-fashioned typedef; e.g.:

`typedef typename Map::key_type K;`

The place where this workaround falls apart is when the type is templated:

```
template<typename T>
using Bar = Foo<T>; // ok if your compiler supports it

template<typename T>
typedef Foo<T> Bar; // doesn't compile
```

But then you still at least have this option:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
   typedef Foo<T> type;
};
```

Comment: It's helpful to note that the syntax in which OP is using it is equivalent to typedef. So any other context may not be implemented at all.